# How can I put my header in top of everything?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My header have the property "position: fixed", but, some images in the body has the property "filter: grayscale(100%)", when I scroll the page, the images are showed in front of my header.

HTML:

```
<header><header>
<img>
<img>
<img>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    position: fixed;
}

img{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

How can i put them behind my header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}
```

If you have other elements with z-index`s set, you'll need to manage them in order.

You can read more about z-index [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/developing-web-components/9781491905685/ch04.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20stacking%20context%20is,opacity%20value%20less%20than%201.)

Answer (score 0):

In the header css rule add this: z-index: 100; position: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use :

```
 z-index:9999
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
header{
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
  }
```

The HTML structure is important while using position: sticky, since it's make the element sticky relative to the parent. And the sticky positioning might not work with a single element made sticky within a parent.